# Чтение огромных файлов (больше 2Гб)

Tags: java, io

Столкнулся с проблемой считывания динамического файла, в который каждую секунду пишется по 50-75 строк. За сутки набегает овер 500 мб инфы. Это все текст. Задача как можно быстрее считывать инфу, сравнить строку с эталонной, и если такая найдена, то создать новый файл и написать его время нахождения.

Загвоздка в том, что с динамическими файлами не работал. Был бы рад примеру с разбивкой файла на 2 (или другое кол-во) части и прочитывать каждой части отдельным потоком.

Вот что получилось:

```
public class ReadFile1 {
    static File file = null;
    static File fileJCO = new File("JCO.log");
    static String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Рабочий стол\\ReadFile1\\test.log";
    static String line;
    static FileReader fileReader = null;
    //static BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String lineLC = null;
    static String wordLC = null;
    static int currentLine = 0;
    static int beginI = 0;
    static int endI = 0;
    static int wordPosition = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            file = new File(path);
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        BufferedWriter outputJCO = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileJCO));
        words.add("TIME        ");
        try {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineLC = line.toLowerCase();
                currentLine++;
                for (String word : words) {
                    wordLC = word.toLowerCase();
                    if (lineLC.contains(wordLC)) {
                        wordPosition = lineLC.lastIndexOf(wordLC);
                        beginI = wordPosition;
                        if (beginI < 10) {
                            beginI = 0;
                        } else {
                            beginI -= 10;
                        }
                        endI = wordPosition;
                        if (endI > (lineLC.length() - wordLC.length() - 10)) {
                            endI = lineLC.length();
                        } else {
                            endI += wordLC.length() + 20;
                        }
                        System.out.println(line.substring(beginI, wordPosition) + word.toUpperCase() +
                                line.substring(wordPosition + wordLC.length(), endI));
                        outputJCO.write(" Ошибка JCO_ERROR_COMMUNICATION: обнаружена в " +
                                line.substring(beginI, wordPosition) + word.toUpperCase() +
                                line.substring(wordPosition + wordLC.length(), endI) + " по серверному времени" + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            outputJCO.close();
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Строчки которые интересуют:

> Caused by: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (102)
>   JCO_ERROR_COMMUNICATION: Connect to SAP gateway failed
>   Connection parameters: TYPE=A DEST=10.35.94.18.976253
>   ASHOST=10.35.94.18 SYSNR=00 GWHOST=10.35.94.18 GWSERV=sapgw00 PCS=1
>   COMM_CP=15
>                                                                                                                                        LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
>   ERROR       partner '10.35.94.18:sapgw00' not reached
>   TIME        Tue Nov 18 09:09:14 2014
>   RELEASE     720
>   COMPONENT   NI (network interface)
>   VERSION     40
>   RC          -10
>   MODULE      ./nibuf.cpp
>   LINE        4634
>   DETAIL      NiBufIConnect: connection pending after 60000ms

В конечном итоге, потенциал приложения по просчитыванию (замерял у себя на сервере): 130000 строк в секунду. Проглотил файл в 5,33Гб. Прочитывает лог находит фразу и со смещением от найденной фразы выводит в другой файл.

Как можно улучшить этот код?

Comment: Потоки вам не помогут, наоборот только замедлят процесс, потому что вы будете упираться в HDD, а не CPU.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание учту.

Comment: Если это реальная задача, которую надо быстро решить, то я бы взял сорсы команды **tail** и добавил получение образца (эталонной строчки) и свой код для нового файла при ее обнаружении. (конечно, следует отметиить, что Java тут абсолютно ни при чем).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Непонятно, в чем именно у вас проблема. Давайте по пунктам:

1) Потоки вам точно не помогут, так как (вам правильно заметили в комментарии) узким местом будет ввод/вывод, а не CPU, и вы только замедлите работу.

2) Если задача состоит в том, что вам нужно при каждом запуске программы разбирать **заново весь** файл, который очень велик, поэтому скорость важна, то вам следует почитать вот это: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly

3) Если же (мне кажется, что это ваш случай) задача состоит в том, что ваша программа должна висеть и постоянно считывать новые данные, приходящие в файл, и обрабатывать их, то все очень просто: читаем построчно и обрабатываем прочитанные данные; если же файл закончился, ненадолго засыпаем (чтобы не загружать процессор), а потом пробуем прочитать новые данные, вдруг они пришли, и так по-кругу. 50-75 строк в секунду -- это совсем немного, никаких особых ухищрений не нужно. Получится что-то вроде:

```
...
String line;

while (true) {
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // Обработка строки
        ...
    }
    // Вышли из цикла, значит данные в файле пока закончились.
    // Засыпаем на секунду, а затем пробуем снова.
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
...
```

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000) интересный вариант, а можно было бы как то запомнить где на данный момент файл завершился что то вроде флага?

Comment: Вы можете использовать для чтения файла RandomAccessFile, у которого есть метод getFilePointer, возвращающий текущую позицию в файле, и метод seek, позволяющий перейти на заданную позицию.

Comment: Можно не большой пример?

Answer (score 1):

Если в файле есть какая-то структура, то все таки лучше писать в БД в виде поля `CLOB/BLOB`. А дальше уже стандартными процедурами индексирования таблиц.

Comment: Структуры как таковой нет, но можно было бы его создать, это я уже потом займусь спс!

Comment: А можно показать пример как разбивать текст на структуры, не когда этого не делал.

Comment: Ну самый дубовый (не самый лучший) - каждую новую строчку считать записью в БД. Или откладываем по 1024 символа +/- до первого пробела после 1024 символов и откладываем в качестве записи. Вообще зависит от того что пишут в файл. Не думаю что там беспорядочное нагромождение символов - наверняка что-то осмысленное. Знать бы что - подсказал бы.

Comment: Добавил в вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Если Вас смущает ситуация того, что файл может быть дописан, то посмотрите в сторону множественного чтения за концом файла.
На англоязычной версии этого ресурса приводится вполне полноценный пример:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
String line;
while (keepReading) {
    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        // Строка пуста, пауза
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    else {
        // Строка получена, можно работать.
    }
}
```

Там же добавлено примечание, мол если вы хотите использовать функционал tail (чтение добавленных строк и игнорирование старых), то после открытия файла сразу позиционируйтесь в конец — `reader.skip (file.length ());`
В целом, этот вариант не является мультипоточным — она реально и не требуется, так как основной тормоз будет во вторичном носителе информации (RAM — первичный, СХД — вторичный).
В отличие от примера выше, в этом однозначно используется буферизированное чтение, которое рекомендовано для ускорения, да более очевидно условное ветвление есть-данные — нет их — отсутствует сравнение после приравнивания, что, на мой взгляд, упрощает читаемость незнакомых текстов. При этом изменением извне keepReading можно прервать цикл. Например, для завершения работы.

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что у меня не буферизированное чтение? Я просто не привел код целиком, лишь проиллюстрировав подход, не загромождая ничего деталями.

Comment: Вадим, не ругайтесь по-мелочам. Добавил слово «однозначно». Думаю, достаточно.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов А можно ссылочку на англо-язычный ресурс.

Comment: Пожалуйста. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f

Answer (score 1):

Если задача реально такова -

> как можно быстрее считывать инфу

, то здесь однозначно мониторинг ФС -  [NIO2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Даже на текущий момент развития носителей инфо, скорость чтения всегда превосходит скорость записи, посему, повесив поток чтения, если не удается быстро сравнить новые строки со старыми (не хватает одного потока CPU), можно раздавать задания на сравнение дочерним потокам, читая оригинал в одном (если хранилище - 1 HDD), либо параллелить читателей (если хранилище промышленное)